# How to link button to current date with a script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

I've copied a script and changed it according to my own spreadsheet. But I havent reached the point yet to have the knowledge what to change in the script.

The button called "Vandaag" is what's suppose to send me to the exact date.

[My current Google Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhOUC.png)

```
  function activateToday() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lr = s.getLastRow();
  var range = s.getRange(4, 2,1,lr).getValues();
   for(var i=0;i<range[0].length;i++){
    if(range[0][i].getDate()+ range[0][i].getMonth()+1 ==new  Date().getDate()+new Date().getMonth()+1 ){
     s.getRange(1,i+1).activate();
      break;
    }}}
```

Comment: How is it supposed to send you the exact date? Write it somewhere, return it?

Comment: If you open "My current Google Spreadsheet" you will see a button "Vandaag". If I push the button I want to jump to the current day. Maybe I explain it wrong in the beginning.

Comment: So you want the page to scroll ?

Comment: Yes exactly, that's what I mean. At column B the dates are shown and it goes down till row 1098. So with the button I can save the scrolling and go directly to the date.


Thank you in advance.

Comment: Somebody know the answer or have some tips?

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using a hyperlink this can be done without a script. In Google sheets you can jump to a specific cell by hyperlinking a reference to the grid and range:

`=HYPERLINK("#gid=0&range=A19","Jump to Cell")`

If you would like the hyperlink to automatically reference today's date and find the cell, you can use the following formula in cell A1:

`=HYPERLINK(SUBSTITUTE("#gid=0&range="&ADDRESS(MATCH(Today()+1,A2:A,0),1, 1),"$",""),"Jump to date")`

The Match function finds today's date in the specified range, and the address function returns the cell reference to be added to the link.

Note: *If your reference range starts below row 1, you will need to add the number of rows not referenced back to the `today` function. In the example above, since I am leaving out cell `A1` I added 1.*

Hope this helps